# Autofilling slider sometimes not at 100%

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

I am filling a slider from zero to max with this function:

```
IEnumerator FillBar() {
    float runtime = manualTime;
    for(float f = 0; f <= runtime; f += Time.deltaTime) {
        manualSlider.value = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1000, f/runtime);
        yield return null;
    }}
```

But no matter if I use "Whole Numbers" or not it either often stops at 998 (+/- a few) and without whole numbers it stops at 998.XXXX
I have a solution to "cheat" around that problem and reset it manually after it "filled up" with this code

```
    IEnumerator FillBar() {
    float runtime = manualTime;
    for(float f = 0; f <= runtime; f += Time.deltaTime) {
        manualSlider.value = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1000, f/runtime);
        yield return null;
    }
    manualSlider.value = 0;
    //stuff happening here
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I want to use the full slider value as trigger for what happens when the slider is filled but when it never reaches 1000 (I even tried with just 1, too. Same problem)
Is there a good fix for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rarely is gonna reach full value when you're using interpolation with Time.deltaTime.
You need to snap your slider to max value when the interpolation ends.

Try this coroutine instead:

```
IEnumerator FillBar(float _time) {
    float _elapsedTime = 0;

    while(_elapsedTime < _time)
    {
        manualSlider.value = Mathf.Lerp(manualSlider.value, 1, (_elapsedTime/_time));
        _elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }

    manualSlider.value = 1;
}
```

Comment: But essentially you're doing the same "cheat" I used. You set it to max manually. But I want the automatically filling to be the solution instead, as it feels dirty to manually do it.

Comment: The thing is you can't really get to the desired value with Lerp as it slows down at the end and sometimes it never reaches the target value. You can't ever be sure if it's gonna return what you want so you need to "cheat" it this way.

Comment: You might try linear interpolation but it's not as smooth as this one.

Comment: Well, then I'll have to stick to the dirty version, crap. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to, you can use linear interpolation with smoothsteps the thing is it's not as smooth and to be honest it's longer code for not much of a difference :) http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/834930/view.html